# Human Counting in java

Tags: java

I have a question regarding to the program. This program allows you to input a number and counts the numbers up to the given number. for ex. input 5, output will be 0 1 2 3 4 5. I have a question on how to add a second given number, for ex. input 5 & 10, output should be 5 6 7 8 9 10. And also vice versa input 10 & 5, output should be the same.
Heres the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Project1{
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   int n;
   public void input()throws IOException{
      System.out.println("Enter the limit: ");
      n=scan.nextInt();
   }

   public void compute(){
      if(n>1)
         System.out.println("First "+n+" natural numbers are: ");
      else
         System.out.println("First "+n+" natural number is: ");
      for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
         System.out.println(i);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
      Project1 obj=new Project1();
      obj.input();
      obj.compute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan two variables `start` and `end` and write FOR loop:

```
for(int i=start; i<=end; i++)
     System.out.println(i);
```

if you want to check if start is greater than end:

```
if(start > end) {
    int temp = start;
    start = end;
    end = temp;
}
```

Comment: Will this allow it to output the same value for ex. input 1 & 5, output = 1 2 3 4 5.. And also input 5 & 1, output will still be 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: If you write that if statement before for loop 1&5 will have same output as 5&1 according to your first post.

Comment: You can vote my answer and mark it that solve you question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the second input from the scanner and use it in your loop.
Here is an example based on your code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Project1{
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   int n;
   int e;
   public void input()throws IOException{
      System.out.println("Enter start: ");
      n=scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter end: ");
      e=scan.nextInt();
   }

   public void compute(){
      if(n>1)
         System.out.println("First "+n+" natural numbers are: ");
      else
         System.out.println("First "+n+" natural number is: ");
      for(int i=n; i<=e; i++)
         System.out.println(i);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
      Project1 obj=new Project1();
      obj.input();
      obj.compute();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreacitate it